# GWT Window.getScrollTop() return zero always

Tags: gwt

GWT  Window.getScrollTop()  return zero always   after last Google chrome update, so always when I call the function  Window.getScrollTop() It gets Zero while it was working in older versions and on IE and FireFox

Comment: Maybe related to https://github.com/gwtproject/gwt/issues/9542

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that updating GWT is not an option I found a workaround for getting the scrollTop value in GWT running on Chrome, using JSNI and jQuery:

```
native int chromeGetScrollTop() /*-{
  return $wnd.jQuery("html").scrollTop();
}-*/;
```